# Filtering key value pair in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have the following select list the ng-model is the `categoryFilter`:

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="categoryFilter" style="text-transform: capitalize;"
        ng-options="category for (category, subCategories) in sportEvents">
        <option value="">Choose Category</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And I have the following list area where I want to filter the results of the list:

```
<div ng-repeat="(category, subCategories) in filtered = (sportEvents | filter: categoryFilter)">
    <div ng-repeat="(subCategory, subCategorySportEvents) in subCategories"
        ng-hide="filtered.length == 0">
        <h4 style="text-transform: capitalize;">{{category}} - {{subCategory}}</h4>
        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover">
            <tr ng-repeat="sportEvent in filtered = (subCategorySportEvents | filter: query | filter: dayFilter)">
                <td class="col-xs-1"><span>{{ sportEvent.number}}</span></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But here the `categoryFilter` does not work. Yes I use other two filtering as you can see, but those work fine (the query and the dayFilter are OK). Maybe the problem is here, that I use a key value pair? (category, subCategory)?
So when I select the category in the select list, it does not filtering the list.

Comment: Log all your variables inside the `ng-repeat`, without employing the filter -- are you sure they're what you expect them to be? It looks to me like `categoryFilter` should be a string, so `sportEvents` should be an array of strings, without keys and values.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. The {{ category }} is a string, but the {{ categoryFilter }} are the array of subCategories, so this is the result. But how should I modify the code?
" are you sure they're what you expect them to be? " - sorry, I do not understand this part.